# SQL Server variables and direct values not returning same results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm working on building a sql query to fetch some details from a table. And I am using a variable that is assigned with a value in where condition. However, when the value assigned to the variable is directly given to the where condition it returns a different result set. I cannot disclose the entire query here due to the nature of work but I hope someone could help me.

```
declare @filterParam varchar(255) = 'Y'
Select .......
from Table A
where 
...
A.column!= @filterParam
```

This returns some number of rows but if i replace the variable with its actual value then 0 rows are returned

```
Select .......
from Table A
where 
...
A.column!= 'Y'
```

0 rows is what the expected result is. But why is the SQL Server returning result when the value is assigned to a variable and used it against the where condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mre] here; the above isn't sufficient for us to tell us why what you have isn't behaving as you expect.

Comment: Sounds very odd.  I'd be curious as to the type and collation of the "column".  Is the collation of the database the same?  Are you sure the case for was the same?